# delete specific words in a file

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I want to delete stop words in a file (it contains a sentence, a tab and then an English word). The stop words are in a separate file and the language is Persian. The code below works, but the problem is, it deletes for example a stop word in a line but it doesn't delete the same stop word in some other line. it happened almost for every stop words. I guessed maybe it can be for normalizing. So I normalized the 2 files by importing the hazm module (hazm is like NLTK, for Persian). But there was no change in the problem. Can some body help?

```
from hazm import*
punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~،؟«؛'

file1 = "stopwords.txt"
file2 = "test/پر.txt"


witoutStops = []
corpuslines = []

def RemStopWords (file1, file2):  
    with open(file1, encoding = "utf-8") as stopfile:
        normalizer = Normalizer()
        stopwords = stopfile.read()
        stopwords = normalizer.normalize(stopwords)
        with open(file2, encoding = "utf-8") as trainfile:
            with open ("y.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as newfile:
                for line in trainfile:
                    tmp = line.strip().split("\t")
                    tmp[0] = normalizer.normalize(tmp[0])
                    corpuslines.append(tmp)
                    for row in corpuslines:
                        line = ""
                        tokens = row[0].split()
                        for token in tokens:
                            if token not in stopwords:
                                line += token + " "
                    line = line.strip() + "\n"
                    for i in punctuation:  # deletes punctuations
                        if i in line:
                            line = line.replace(i, "")
                    newfile.write(line)
                    witoutStops.append (line)
```

stop words file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/irjkjmwkzwnnpnk/stopwords.txt?dl=0

file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4m8san3xhr0pdj/%D9%BE%D8%B1.txt?dl=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete stop words using regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417528/delete-stop-words-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. That's because in some words the punctuation attaches to the word and the code counts it as a part of the word not punctuation. If the punctuation be deleted first, by moving the 3 lines of the code which belong to this part under the line " tmp[0] = normalizer.normalize(tmp[0])", and then delete stop words, all of the stop words will be omitted.